# Angular App not running inside Azure App Service

Tags: angular, azure, github-actions, azure-appservice

I am having problems deploying my Angular App to a new Azure App service.

I set up deployment correctly. For CI, I set it up so it checks my github repo on the main branch and redeploys if there is a check in. It created a github actions yml file and I updated it to install, build, and deploy my app. I have verified that it is deploying the built files. When I push to that branch my github action workflow is kicked off which is detected by the Deployment Center for my App service and it completes successfully.

When I navigate to the url for the application page I get the message "Your web app is running and waiting for your content".

I have verified that my files have uploaded into the site/wwwroot/ directory through the scm.azurewebsites.net debug console. When I deploy changes, the files in that directory reflect the changes. I have tried including a web.config file that worked with a previous Angular App on an App Service. I have verified that it too is uploaded into the root folder as well.

Nothing works. It looks like I have everything in place, only it doesn't recognize the content. How do I get the app service to recognize my content/index.html file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things you're going to want to check:

1. Make sure that you've correctly set your `Runtime Stack` to `Node {Version}`
2. You're going to need the correct path to your Angular site and in `App Settings --> Configuration --> General Settings` you'll want to add the following to `Startup Command`:

```
pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot --no-daemon --spa
```

Obviously, you'll want to replace your path in the command.

UPDATE:
If your Angular App is a static site, you might want to look into hosting the site using an `Azure Storage Account`. You can create a new `Azure Storage Account`, and once the resource is created, you can use the `Data management --> Static Website` option to set your Storage Account up to serve static content.
If you'd like to add a custom domain and SSL certificates, you can then create a new `CDN Profile` that serves the files from your `$web` directly in your newly created storage account.
Personally, I've found that this method works excellently and reduces hosting costs.
You can find a full walk-through for this [here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website-host)

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much. Yes, I have considered a static site and I orginally started out with creating one, its just that the default url is ugly. I'm going off of a free tier to begin with and I need to be able to pass my url around and people be able to recognize it. I'm already paying for other parts of my architecture so I'm trying to keep costs low.

Comment: If the answer resolved your issue, it'd be great if you could mark it as `accepted` so that users in the future can also benefit from the information here! Thanks!